# Why an I getting redudant "None" element in python?

Tags: python, file, csv

I have this code which I am using to read my dataset from csv file with the CSV module:

```
keys = []

def ahencrypt(row):
    for field in row:
        print field

def read_data(filename):
    import csv
    with open(filename, "rb") as csvfile:
        datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in datareader:
            yield row

for row in read_data('dataset/car.data'):
        print ahencrypt(row)
```

My data has just 7 columns, but after reading each row the program is giving my redudant `None` value. I can't understand the problem here. Can anyone please have a look at it?

PS: I am using [this](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/car+evaluation) dataset

Comment: Please include the minimal amount of sample data required to reproduce the problem. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just remove the print statement before the ahencrypt function

Answer (score 1):

Your `ahencrypt` function prints things and returns None.  Your code at the end prints the return value of `ahencrypt`, which is None.  You can just remove the `print` in the last line of your code.

Comment: Thanks. I completely missed that last print statement

Answer (score 0):

Your `ahencrypt` function prints a line and implicitly returns a `None`. You then print that `None` in this loop:

```
for row in read_data('dataset/car.data'):
        print ahencrypt(row)
```